# How to set a variable with type List<T> to a value with type ArrayList<T> using the constructor

Tags: java, list, constructor

An implementation of a graph node is as follows (I cannot change the implementation as it is from a coding website):

```
class Node {
    public int val;
    public List<Node> neighbors;
    public Node(int _val, ArrayList<Node> _neighbors) {
        val = _val;
        neighbors = _neighbors;
    }
}
```

If I pass a node to my copyGraph function below, I wouldn't be able to make a copy of that node by calling the Node constructor because I get

> incompatible types: List cannot be converted to ArrayList

```
class Solution {
    public Node copyGraph(Node node) {
        Node n = new Node(node.val, node.neighbors);
        //do some code
    }
}
```

How else could I make a new Node with this implementation?

Comment: Why is this constructor taking in an `ArrayList` instead of just taking in a `List`: `public Node(int _val, List<Node> _neighbors)`?

Comment: Not sure, the question is from one of the coding interview websites..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem

That API is poorly designed, FYI. The constructor should accept a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) rather than `ArrayList`. Ideally that code would be:

```java
public Node ( int _val , List < Node > _neighbors ) { … }
```

… or perhaps even the more general [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) if order were unimportant.

```java
public Node ( int _val , Collection < Node > _neighbors ) { … }
```

## Workaround

Two ways to work around that poor design: cast, or copy.

- If you know for sure that your `List` object is actually an `ArrayList`, cast as shown in the correct [Answer by coconan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69983165/642706).
- If you are not sure of the concrete implementation of your `List` object, construct a new `ArrayList` while passing your `List`.

```java
Node n = new Node ( node.val, new ArrayList < Node > ( nodesList ) );
```

Comment: Also of note: the question indicates that this is to make a copy. The second option that makes a new `ArrayList` is a good idea so that they are distinct lists. Having two different nodes internally refer to the same list will probably lead to some unwanted behavior - it _might_ be fine, but I strongly doubt that. Ideally, the constructor itself would make that copy for the field.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast node.neighbors to `ArrayList` with **(ArrayList<Node>)** `node.neighbors`

```
class Solution {
    public Node copyGraph(Node node) {
        Node n = new Node(node.val, (ArrayList<Node>) node.neighbors);
        //do some code
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a good idea.